# My Kia soul won't start when rainy or very cold

Tags: battery, starter, kia, soul

The dealer can't find anything wrong. Once I clutch start it I don't have the problem anymore. Until it is really rainy or cold a again. 
The Kia dealer can't find anything wrong. Do you think it could be the starter or solenoid?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the battery, look at the age on it(label says somewhere) if its over 3+ years or whenever the warranty goes off its worth replacing.